# Mistake in an EF Migration better to rollback, delete, re-add or just simply add new

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I created a large migration that creates my initial schema and ran database update.

Afterwards I noticed that a field that is supposed to be of type DateTime is accidentally of type string. I fixed it in my model.

Now should I update the database to a migration prior to the one with the mistake, delete the bad migration, then re-add the migration again. Or just simply add a new migration that only patches the fix.

The reason I am leaning towards rolling back, deleting, then re-adding is because I wouldn't want any messed up migrations with incorrect info would I? I feel like it is pointless to have migrations that are incorrect.

I believe the confusion comes in for me because I have never used migrations in a production environment so I don't think I am aware of the power of them. So I would like someone to clear up whether old migrations can have mistakes or if they should all be free of mistakes and show the entire progress of the database as I add new models / entities.

Comment: Personally, I use migrations for a single purpose: to update remote UAT and PROD databases. When I first start developing a greenfield app, I will use one of the DropCreate initializers and not even bother with migrations. When I get ready to deploy, I switch to migrations. I am always rolling my migrations up similar to what Chris describes [here](http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1).

Comment: @SteveGreene do you use the Entity Framework DropCreate feature? If so do you know how to implement it in EF Core 1.0 (EF7)

Comment: Sorry, missed the core tag. It's different, but doable: use Database.EnsureDeleted followed by Database.EnsureCreated. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3042

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt614250.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are just a tool to help you preserve data between schema changes. They're especially handy for managing multiple database servers like dev/test/production or dev-local databases in team environments.

If you only have one server, then rewriting a migration is cheap, so go ahead and correct it this way.

If everyone on your team has already applied the migration, or you've applied it to databases with data you would like to preserve, then it would be simpler to update the column using a new migration.

In other words, there is no right or wrong way to use Migrations, only a cost associated with rewriting history.